# How to fix XML preview font in Android Studio 3.1.4

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, preview

The XML preview font is not clear. This problem happened after I updated Android Studio to version 3.1.4. I use Droid Sans font in the XML editor.
How can I fix this problem or change the font type in the XML preview?

[image: Preview]

Comment: Try changing the App Theme in Preview window.

Answer (score 0):

If your font appears on the emulator but not in the preview, you should first double check the AppTheme dropdown menu in the preview screen like Jaimin said.

If it still doesn't appear, double check that the font is properly located in your assets/fonts folder OR in your res/font folder, and in the attribute tab "Include font in project" has been selected.